# Form: Honeypot spam issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms

I'd like to use honeypot instead of recaptcha for spam. I'm running WordPress. Normally, I would use Gravity forms for this, but, I didn't develop this site and they are using carbon fields to populate form fields.

I need a conditional in the following js, i.e. if $robotest !="" echo "this is spam" else submit form. My honeypot form field is robotest (var $robotest = $this.find(['[name="robotest"]']);).

Here is the entire chunk of code that is submitting the form:

```js
$('.form-suite form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var is_valid = true;
  var data_to_send = {};

  var $this = $(this);

  console.log('FORM SUBMITTED!!!!');

  console.log('ap test');

  console.log($('#event_dates').val());

  console.log(grecaptcha);



  var $team_artist_event = $this.find('[name="team-artist-event"]');
  var $booking_event = $this.find('[name="game"]');
  var $first_name = $this.find('[name="fname"]');
  var $last_name = $this.find('[name="lname"]');
  var $company = $this.find('[name="company"]');
  var $email = $this.find('[name="email"]');
  var $phone = $this.find('[name="phone"]');
  var $contact_method = $this.find('[name="contact-method"]');
  var $comments = $this.find('[name="comments"]');
  var $sell_suite = $this.find(['[name="sell_suite"]']);
  var $corporate_outings = $this.find(['[name="corporate_outings"]']);
  var $event_dates = $this.find(['[name="event_dates"]']);
  var $how_many = $this.find(['[name="how_many"]']);
  var $robotest = $this.find(['[name="robotest"]']);

  console.log('AARON HI dates:' + $event_dates.val());


  $this.find('.required').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:  #ddd;');

    var field_value = $(this).val();
    if (field_value == '') {
      $(this).attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(255, 40, 40, 0.25) !important;');
      is_valid = false;
    }
  });

  //var captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  //if (captcha == '') {
  //is_valid = false;
  //$('.captcha').attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(255, 40, 40, 0.25) //!important;');
  //}
  var email_regex = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
  if (!email_regex.test($email.val())) {
    $email.attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(255, 40, 40, 0.25) !important;');
    is_valid = false;
  }

  if (is_valid) {
    data_to_send.team_artist_event = $team_artist_event.val();
    data_to_send.booking_event = $booking_event.val();
    data_to_send.first_name = $first_name.val();
    data_to_send.last_name = $last_name.val();
    data_to_send.company = $company.val();
    data_to_send.email = $email.val();
    data_to_send.phone = $phone.val();
    data_to_send.contact_method = $contact_method.val();
    data_to_send.comments = $comments.val();
    data_to_send.sell_suite = $sell_suite.val();
    data_to_send.corporate_outings = $corporate_outings.val();
    data_to_send.action = 'booking_form';
    data_to_send.event_dates = $('#event_dates').val();
    data_to_send.how_many = $('#how_many').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
      data: data_to_send,
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {


        if (data.status == 'OK') {

          console.log('GA send');
          ga('send', {
            'hitType': 'pageview',
            'page': '/form-submit/team' // Virtual page (aka, does not actually exist) that you can now track in GA Goals as a destination page.
          });

          ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'submitted', 'Team Form');

          window.location.href = '/thank-you.php';

          //$('.personal-info, .event-info').hide();
          //$(' .event-info').before('<h2 class="form-success-msg">' + data.message + '</h2>');
        }




      },
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Aside from what you're asking ... your `email_regex` is far too strict and will exclude many _many_ valid email addresses, including everything from newer (longer) TLD like `.museum` and many legal characters outside of the `[a-z0-9._%+-]+` to the left of the **@** -- see [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Any ideas for the honeypot question?

Comment: So if I've got this clear, `$robotest` should always be empty unless a robot found it and filled it out. Then a test for not-empty would mean is_valid should be false, and that test could be done where you have the captcha test commented out... `if ($robotest.val().length > 0) { is_valid = false; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The honeypot field `<input name="robotest">` should always be empty if a human filled out the form, because that field is hidden away from humans.  A robot filling in the form blindly would (might) find that field and put some value in it.

Your example has your captcha code commented out...

```
//var captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
//if (captcha == '') {
//is_valid = false;
```

In place of that you can just test the honeypot field to make sure it is empty.

```
if ($robotest.val().length > 0) {
    is_valid = false;
}
```

You can go on and skip the rest of the tests (return early) when `!is_valid` or even just return immediately:

```
if ($robotest.val().length > 0) {
    return;
}
```

If your caller/handler is set up to be ready for that.

Comment: Neither option is working. Here is the honeypot field js I'm using:

Comment: `var $robotest = $this.find(['[name="robotest"]']);
if ($robotest.val().length > 0) {
 $robotest.attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(255, 40, 40, 0.25) !important;');
 is_valid = false;
}`

Comment: functions.js is submitting the form. Works perfectly until I add the honeypot code above. Here's more relevant code:

Comment: Link to functions.js -var $robotest.... is around line 215:  [Form JS](view-source:https://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/wp-content/themes/luxury-vip-suites-new-child/js/functions.js?ver=1489632053).

Comment: Looking for a solution to this. I'm not sure why the honeypot validation isn't working. This is the link to functions.js: [https://www.luxuryvipsuites.com/wp-content/themes/luxury-vip-suites-new-child/js/functions.js?ver=1489632053] The robotest validation starts at line 215

Comment: `var $robotest = $this.find(['[name="robotest"]']);
   if ($robotest.val().length > 0) {
    $robotest.attr('style', 'background-color: rgba(255, 40, 40, 0.25) !important;');
    is_valid = false;
}`